# DTV Data from IEEE 802.22 Meeting in May 2006

Tags: signal-processing

I am currently working on some signal sensing algorithms. In various papers I have come across the reference to DTV signal data that they used for their simulations, amongst others: [Reference number 21](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.719.9363&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

They led me to this [web page](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/22/Meeting_documents/), which seems to be an official repository with all meeting documents of the IEEE 802.22 working group.

Going into the May 2006 directory leads me to this [page](https://www.ieee802.org/22/Meeting_documents/2006_May/index.html), where the top entry is probably what I am looking for.
There should be a FTP link to some DTV data. However, the only link present there takes me to this [page](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/22/Meeting_documents/2006_May/Informal_Documents/), where only graphical plots and some meta information about the DTV data is available, but no signal data files.

The guy who allegedly took these samples seems to be called Victor Tawil and used to work for a company called MSTV. A powerpoint with more info about the signal data but no data or link is [here](https://mentor.ieee.org/802.22/dcn/06/22-06-0038-00-0000-dtv-signal-captures.ppt).

If any of you know where I can find that signal data (it is most likely going to be IQ-data stored as stereo channels inside a WAV file) or have any idea what to do next, please let me know.

Thank you

PS: I have already tried emailing Victor